# Где покупается лицензия на шрифт?

Tags: css, web-fonts

Скажите, пожалуйста.

1. Где покупается шрифт museo700? Говорят, что на myfonts нечего его покупать.
2. Мне нужен для сайта данный шрифт и, если я куплю веб-лизенцию,
   то мне должны предоставить исходники всех веб-шрифтов в формате:

   > src: url('../fonts/WebFont.eot');
   >
   > src: url('../fonts/WebFont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
   >
   > url('../fonts/WebFont.woff') format('woff'),
   >
   > url('../fonts/WebFont.woff') format('woff2'),
   >
   > url('../fonts/WebFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   >
   > url('../fonts/WebFont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
3. Я должна платить за эти шрифты ежемесячно в зависимости от количества просмотров?

Comment: как бы [вот правообладатель](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/museo-cyrillic/) вот  с ним и свяжитесь он всё объяснит , иностранцы очень порядочные и ведут себя крайне профессионально

Comment: @UbuntuUser MyFonts не правообладатель, а, фактически, реселлер. Но объяснения, разумеется, будут :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov я о MyFonts ни слова не сказал а лишь написал о [Jos Buivenga](https://www.myfonts.com/person/Jos_Buivenga/)

Comment: @UbuntuUser тогда прошу прощения за непонимание :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Museo700` бесплатен для определенных случаев использования. Вы можете  [зарегистрироваться](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/museo/700/#index) и "купить" его за 0 долларов для использования **на персональном компьютере (для себя лично)** и на **веб-сайте** (бесконечное количество просмотров). При этом вам предоставят для скачивания веб-кит, включающий EOT, TTF, WOFF и WOFF2, и, разумеется, OTF.

Остальные варианты использования (кроме eAds) - платные.

Comment: спасибо Вам, а если мне за 900 купить https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/museo/900/glyphs.html#style/154924
То есть инфа о лизенции в виде кода размещается в шапке сайта перед подключением css в виде кода, 
`!--
/**
 * @license
 * MyFonts Webfont Build ID code
, 2018-11-14T00:28:34-0500
 *
 * © 2018 MyFonts Inc
*/`
и на платный и бесплатный шрифт. В таком случае могут скопировать лизенцию посредством просмотра кода страницы. Что-то непонятно....

Comment: Пусть копируют :) Она привязана к вашему экаунту. И если возникнет проблема, вы всегда докажете для своего сайта, когда и как вы брали разрешение на использование а они (т.е. те, кто скопировал) - нет.